# OSX 10.11 remote login without taking over display

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I want to be able to run updates for a few computers all from my desktop, while the users of those computers are logged in and working. Is there any way to log in to a remote computer as it's Admin, while another user is logged in under their user name so that I can use the desktop as the admin without taking over their screen?

Answer (score 2):

Why use the desktop?  I would just log in via ssh and use the 'softwareupdate' command.

More information on using this tool can be [found here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200113) on Apple's site.